# Can I write and read SocketChannel at once?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I have an object (socketChannel) of `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` opened.

And `socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);`

Is it safe:

1. Write to it from one thread,
2. Read from it in another thread,

at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have one thread writing to the `SocketChannel`, while one thread is reading from it.

From the Javadoc:

> Socket channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. They
>   support concurrent reading and writing, though at most one thread may
>   be reading and at most one thread may be writing at any given time.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html